# I'm getting Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG with selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar

Tags: testng, selenium-server

I'm getting Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG with selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar. But the same works fine with selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.

Command i used to run from cmd: java -cp bin;jarslib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

All the jars in my JarsLib folder.

Trying to execute my tests through cmd prompt. All the tests works fine inside the eclipse.

If i add 2.39V jar, and execute this, works fine. But if i use 3.9.1V jar, it simply gives an error " Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG "

I don't know, what are all the new dependencies to make it run with 3.9.0V. It would be much helpful to list all the dependencies jars list, so that i can add to my work space.

I'm using Java-project. So handling dependencies is problem here.

Can some one helps me to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please let us know what you are doing to simulate the error? Please share the command line command you are using along with the error stacktrace

Comment: Added sir, Please review and let me know your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your project's classpath. Selenium 2.39.0 used to be bundled with TestNG classes. That explains why things worked for you when you were using Selenium 2.39.0 everything was working fine.

```
jar -tf selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar | grep -i 'org.testng.TestNG.class' 
org/testng/TestNG.class
```

But the same is not true anymore with the latest selenium binaries. To get this sorted out you have two options.

1. You download TestNG jar and make it available in your `jarslib` folder (You would need to download [testng-6.14.2.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/6.14.2/testng-6.14.2.jar),  [jcommander-1.72.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/beust/jcommander/1.72/jcommander-1.72.jar) and [bsh-2.0b6.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache-extras/beanshell/bsh/2.0b6/bsh-2.0b6.jar) ] (or)
2. You leverage a build tool such as maven or gradle and then add up dependencies to TestNG as detailed in the official documentation [here](http://testng.org/doc/download.html)

and then try again.

Comment: Dear Krishnan, This really helps and worked perfectly. I'm really thankful to you for make me to understand and worked.